# Exclude dash (-) from word separators in vi

Tags: unix, vi, ctags

vi uses dash and space as word separators.
is there any way to exclude dash from word separators ?

This is required to work with the symbols generated by ctags exe.
when symbol contain a "-" ,vi tags fails to locate that even though symbol is generated properly.

For example 
 Symbol - EX01-VAR-LOCAL
when using the ctrl+] to search tag for this, vi looks only for EX01 not the complete symbol EX01-VAR-LOCAL

although if used with vi -t EX01-VAR-LOCAL or in command mode :tag EX01-VAR-LOCAL
works fine.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: sorry, not a programming (code) question Voting to move to superuser.com . Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i found iskeyword is not supported by vi.

Answer (score 1):

To unset dash as a word separator you have to set this as a normal character using '**iskeyword**' setting.

If you look the default **iskeyword** content (using ":set all") you may have this:

iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255

The dash symbol is 45 in ASCII characters, so you have to set as normal character.

Try this:

set iskeyword=@,45,48-57,_,192-255

Answer (score 0):

FZapp's answer is correct.  The only thing I'd like to add is that looking at the content of `iskeyword` would be easier using `:set iskeyword` instead of `:set all`.